# ProcessBatchData CAML Mass Delete SPListItems

Tags: powershell, caml

Attempting to bulk delete List Item using ProcessBatchData in a PowerShell script.  Here is a command that my code is generating but I am getting an error when it executes. I have been unable to find the problem so I am hoping some CAML experts can shed some light as to what I am doing wrong.

```
$spWeb.ProcessBatchData("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Batch><Method><SetList Scope='Request'>b37425b3-189d-4031-97f6-15e4ca767185</SetList><SetVar Name='ID'>480</SetVar><SetVar Name='Cmd'>Delete</SetVar></Method></Batch>");
```

Here is the Error:

```
Exception calling "ProcessBatchData" with "1" argument(s): "<nativehr>0x80070057</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>"
At line:1 char:24
+ $spWeb.ProcessBatchData <<<< ("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Batch><Method><SetList Scope='Request'>b37425b3-189d-4031-97f6-15e4ca767185</SetList><SetVar Name='ID'>480</SetVar><SetVar Name='Cmd'>Delete</SetVar></Method></Batch>");
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It ended up being sloppy escape characters in my XML.  Powershell uses backtick character to excape characters and I was using single quotes and other techniques.  After switching to proper escaping character my command worked.  See blog post [here](http://www.theodells.org/theodells/blog/2012/10/powershell-function-to-delete-all-sharepoint-list-items/) for more.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<ows:Batch>`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ows:Batch OnError='Return'>
  <Method>
    <SetList Scope='Request'>b37425b3-189d-4031-97f6-15e4ca767185</SetList>
    <SetVar Name='ID'>480</SetVar>
    <SetVar Name='Cmd'>Delete</SetVar>
  </Method>
</ows:Batch>
```

`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><ows:Batch OnError='Return'><Method><SetList Scope='Request'>b37425b3-189d-4031-97f6-15e4ca767185</SetList><SetVar Name='ID'>480</SetVar><SetVar Name='Cmd'>Delete</SetVar></Method></ows:Batch>`

From [Deleting Items using ProcessBatchData method](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopment/thread/65edfd5e-b916-4349-acfb-bbee796777e1)

Comment: Aside from that, it appears that your CAML is well formed. The only similar issues I've found, the error is resolved by allowing unsafe updates, the error is caused by a read-only field, or the error is caused by a bad CAML-produced content type.